# Detail Disclosure Button Color Global Tint

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Is there a way to have the detail disclosure button take on the red global tint of my app? In the screenshot you can see that my navigation bar button items have taken on the global tint. However, when I add a detail disclosure button to my annotation it does not have the red tint. Below is my code to add the detail disclosure button.

```
      let rightButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
      rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapViewController.showLocationDetails(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
      annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

[image: MapView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, you have to create a custom information disclosure button, and add it to the view.

```
UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
[myAccessoryButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_red_accessory_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I will have to manually create the button. Since my bar button items automatically took on the tint, I thought the detail disclosure button might as well.

Comment: You re welcome. Can you accept my answer and +1 please